# Do javascript loaders replace the need to do script combining?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, loader

Do script loaders replace the need to do script combining?

Or are they really complementary tools?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript loaders only defer JavaScript loading and provide **lazy load** or **on-demand load** experience for us. But they don't reduce HTTP requests. Thus, it totally depends. If you load 200KB of JavaScript as a combined file at first and only use 10KB, then you'd better separate JavaScript codes into their original files and use a loader to defer loading process to increase your performance.

Answer (score 6):

complementary ... script loaders are only for optional or occasional dependencies. combining scripts is about optimizing the scripts that you know you will always need on a page

Comment: "script loaders are only for optional or occasional dependencies" how does this statement account for discrete always needed dependencies such as jQuery for example. Combining jQuery with your personal scripts would generally be viewed as an antipattern.

Comment: good point. For my projects, I always keep jquery as a separate reference (so it can be cached separately). combining is for my own global scripts and any jquery plugins that I use across the site.

Answer (score 2):

Usually scriptloades will not/can not combine your javascript files on the fly, unless you're using some kind of optimizating proxy or have some logic up and running on the serverside.

One scriptloader which does both (combining + transfering) is [supplyJS](https://github.com/jAndreas/Supply).

Comment: I definitely wasn't considering the thought of the loader doing BOTH combining and loading. supplyJS is an interesting project.